# Can't import library into Google App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, jar, google-cloud-storage, gae-eclipse-plugin

I use the Google App Engine SDK 1.8.5 with Eclipse 3.8 on Ubuntu.

I want to add the Cloud Storage service to my app, so I downloaded `guava-gwt-15.0.jar` and `appengine-gcs-client-0.3.jar`, and put them in my apps `/war/WEB-INF/lib/` folder. I also added these jars to the build path in Eclipse.

When I fire up my app in dev mode, it runs fine, at least until I try to access a page relevant to the GCS library. When I do that, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.<init>(GcsServiceImpl.java:35)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:32)
... etc
```

I cleaned my project and restarted Eclipse multiple times, and still the problem persists. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Guava for GWT, you also need the core Guava library ([`guava-15.0.jar`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)). Download the .jar to `war/WEB-INF/lib` and add it to you build path as well.